# MailEnable - Management tool?

Tags: email

At the moment we use Plesk to manage mail accounts (Via a MailEnable Mail Server) however, we are thinking of scraping plesk.

Are there any managment panels out there for controling email server settings?

Answer (score 0):

We use [Postfixadmin](http://postfixadmin.sourceforge.net/) to manage our accounts "Postfix Admin is a web based interface used to manage mailboxes, virtual domains and aliases. It also features support for vacation/out-of-the-office messages." 
Can also be integrated into squirrelmail webmail.

Answer (score 0):

Plesk only makes much sense if you're providing a hosted service. What else you might use depends on the scale of your operation. IMHO GoSA (an LDAP frontend and schema) is a very good solution even for smallish environments. vimbadmin is a convenient tool for postfix. There are lots more available.

Comment: We are not server-admins. What you have just said, if I'm honest was just Jargon :)

Answer (score 0):

ViMbAdmin was created as a modern replacement for PostfixAdmin. Check it out at http://code.google.com/p/vimbadmin/.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just rely on MailEnable's own management tool? It allows web based interface for management but the limitation is to assign mailbox as Admin for management. You can assign one mailbox from every domain as Admin so user can create more mailboxes.

Answer (score 0):

The professional version of Mailenable has a web administration function but costs $350. I have used Mailenable Pro and it is good.

If you are considering scrapping Plesk the presumably you will be managing other server functions by remote desktop. The management interface to Mailenable you can access this way for all versions and is easy to use. The downside being only people you trusted with remote desktop access to the server would b able to administer mail accounts.

Other than full server control panels I am not aware of any other software that can act as a front end to Plesk.

If you are thinking of changing mailserver then on windows [hmail](http://www.hmailserver.com/) is worth looking at it has many more feature than mailenable standard and is free has webmail but no standalone web administration. there is a GUI to use by remote desktop though.